# looping secondary json array, selecting specific array

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops

I recently asked a question about looping an array which was answered and worked with this:

**Answer Marked.**

**My own modified Answer is below too.**

JSON

```
{"product": [{
    "title":"Product One",
    "price":"Price One",
    "desc":"Description One"
  }]
}
```

PHP

```
  foreach($product['product'] as $value) {
    echo "Title : " .$value['title'];
  }
```

I've been trying to figure out how to loop a second level(?) array such as this `image` array.

JSON

```
{"product": [{
    "title":"Product One",
    "price":"Price One",
    "desc":"Description One",
    "image": [{
        "img":"image 1 1"
    },{
        "img":"image 1 2"
    },{
        "img":"image 1 3"
    }]
}, {
    "title":"Product Two",
    "price":"Price Two",
    "desc":"Description Two",
    "image": [{
        "img":"image 2 1"
    },{
        "img":"image 2 2"
    },{
        "img":"image 2 3"
    }]
}]
}
```

So far I've tried this:

```
<?php
    foreach($product['product']['image'] as $value) {
      echo "Image: " .$value['img'] . "<br>";
  }
?>
```

and

```
<?php
    foreach($product['product'] as $value) {
      echo "Image: " .$value['image']['img'] . "<br>";
  }
?>
```

As well as a few variations of similar ideas.

My desired output is:

```
Image: image 1 1
Image: image 1 2
Image: image 1 3
Image: image 2 1
Image: image 2 2
Image: image 2 3
```

Also, how would I go about selecting an array via a value eg..

JSON

```
{"product": [{
    "id":"001"
    "title":"Product One",
    "price":"Price One",
    "desc":"Description One"
  },{
    "id":"002"
    "title":"Product One",
    "price":"Price One",
    "desc":"Description One"
  }]
}
```

PHP

```
 if ( isset( $product['product']['id'] && $product['product']['id'] == "001") ) {
  foreach(*specific array as $value) {
    echo "Title : " .$value['title'] . "<br>";
    echo "Price : " .$value['price'] . "<br>";
  }
```

etc..

I was thinking a better way would be to set the array as the id so I can just say go grab array `{"product": [{"001": [{"title:..."002": [{...` instead of product with a value of `001` for the key `id`. Just not sure about a lot of things so it's hard to find my errors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have some mistakes on your loop, you can see my answer and demo

Comment: going to work on the second part of the question bms, for now - answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first section you can use following;

```
<?php
    foreach($product['product'] as $value) {
        foreach($value["image"] as $image) {
            echo "Image: " .$image['img'] . "<br>"; 
        }

  }
?>
```

Here is a working demo: **[Demo](http://codepad.org/Q3wernBH)**

For the second part you can use following;

```
function getArrValue($key, &$product) {
        foreach ($product["product"] as $product) {
            if (!empty($product["id"]) && $product["id"] == $key) {
                return $product;
            }
        }
    }

var_dump(getArrValue("001", $product));
```

You can see demo here: **[Demo](http://codepad.org/Cgz63FXo)**

Comment: perfect, very simple indeed.

Comment: @rwxes thanks. Also you can see my answer and demo for second part of your question

Comment: it seems the second part only displays content for 001 even if 002 is set.. http://codepad.org/WyMnITjY

Comment: Sorry, it is my huge mistake. I forgot to check key value. See my updated answer and demo

Answer (score 1):

You will need to iterate over the first dimension before you can iterate over the second dimension:

```
foreach ($data['product'] as $product) {
    //echo "Title : " . $product['title'] . "\n";
    foreach ($product['image'] as $image) {
        echo "Image: {$image['img']}\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: again - perfect, very simple indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $key=>$value to get property name

```
foreach($product['product'] as $key=>$value){
    if  ($key =="image"){
       foreach($value as $img){
          echo "Image: ".$img;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a small solution which fits my needs based off **paulitto's** answer.

PHP

```
foreach($product['product'] as $key=>$value){
    if ($value['id'] =="001") {
      echo "Title: " .$value['title']."<br>";
        foreach($value['image'] as $img){
          echo "Image: " .$img['img']."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Title: Product One
Image: image 1 1
Image: image 1 2
Image: image 1 3
```

Thanks everyone.